# Prestashop invoice sending on click instead of automatic

Tags: invoice, prestashop-1.5

I am working on prestashop 1.5.3 shop.
At this moment invoice is sent upon order, instead I need it to be sent on confirmation, since i do not always have product in place and it sometimes need time to get, so i can't take money for something i do not have.

Managing product quantity would be a pain, so i would rather write some code to change default behavior, but before starting i would like to see some insight from you guys. Maybe someone already solved this problem or have some leads on files where i could make changes to change the behavior.

Any tips, help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

I figured it out. Invoices can be edited according to your needs inside pdf folder. 
In invoice section you can select when it is sent. 
The mail template can be edited in Mail folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can in the order statuses generate or not the invoice, so you just have to disable the invoice generation for the desired status, and activate it on another.

Regards,